# EF and Multiple Instances of IHostedService

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, entity-framework, azureservicebus

I have multiple IHostedService (BackgroundService) instances registered in my DI container.

```
services.AddHostedService<ResourceMatchingMessageListeningService>();
services.AddHostedService<ResourceMatchingMessageListeningService2>();
services.AddHostedService<ResourceMatchingMessageListeningService3>();
services.AddHostedService<ResourceMatchingMessageListeningService4>();
services.AddHostedService<ResourceMatchingMessageListeningService5>();
```

Each service listens to a different Azure Service Bus queue.  When receiving a message it writes to an database through EF Core.  If I run a single service it works fine, as soon as I run 2 or more I get the error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation
> completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same
> instance of DbContext.

I'm assuming this error comes up because EF Core is not thread safe and the hosted services all run in different threads.

I tired to fix this by setting EF's service lifetime to be transient), but I still get the same error.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sqlServerOptions => 
            sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(120)),
            ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Any suggestion on a potential solution here?

Comment: have you tried scoped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to Create a new service scope for each hosted service, then request your DbContext from that scope.

```
using var scope = services.CreateScope();
var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDataContext>();
```

You might want to create a service scope for each message you process. Perhaps even a separate scoped service to handle the processing of each message.

Unfortunately the implementation then starts to look like a service locator anti-pattern.